# Вопрос про конструирование элемента std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, size_t> Counters;
// ...
++Counters[someString];
```

Допустим, в контейнере не было пары с заданным ключом. Тогда это приводит ко вставке в контейнер новой пары, а затем второй член пары увеличивается на единицу.

Я бы хотел знать, произойдет ли при вставке новой пары таким способом предварительная инициализация второго члена пары (счетчика типа `size_t`) нулем? И почему?

С одной стороны, у элементарных типов нет конструкторов, поэтому, полагаю, в счетчике может оказаться мусор. Но, с другой стороны...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, произойдёт.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at

> When the default allocator is used, this results in the key being copy
> constructed from key and the mapped value being value-initialized.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization

> otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization

> If T is a scalar type, the object's initial value is the integral
> constant zero explicitly converted to T.

P.S.: не забывайте указывать `std::` для `std::size_t`

Comment: Если правильно понял доку, то 0 переменная целого типа, будет проинициализирована только при использовании 11 стандарта и выше.

Comment: @JK_Action `std::unordered_map` появился в 11 стандарте

Comment: @dlm0n а переменные есть в любом стандарте.

Comment: @JK_Action тогда не понял вопроса. Это как-то относится к вопросу ТС или моему ответу? Какой тип инициализации используется? Если у вас возник какой-то новый вопрос по инициализации, то задайте его отдельно вместе с кодом, чтобы было понятно, о чём речь

Comment: @dlm0n  Это было уточнение, по поводу инициализации переменных в целом. Но я не до конца уверен, что правильно понял документацию.